# Can I use a base class in a visitor to std::variant

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, variant, visitor-pattern

Working the basis of a simple template based state machine, and I have the code below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <variant>
#include  <utility>
using namespace std;

class A{}; class B{}; class C{};


template <typename... Types>
class StateHolder{
public:
    template <typename Visitor>
    void Visit(Visitor& v){
        std::visit(
            [&](auto& state){v.Visit(state);},
            m_state);
    }

    template <typename State>
    void SetState(){
        m_state = State{};
    }
private:
    std::variant<Types...> m_state;
};

class PrintVisitor{
public:
    void Visit(const A& a){std::cout << "a\n";}
    void Visit(const B& b){std::cout << "b\n";}
    void Visit(const C& c){std::cout << "c\n";}
};

class DoNothing{
public:
    virtual void Visit(const A&){}
    virtual void Visit(const B&){}
    virtual void Visit(const C&){}
};

class PrintAVisitor : public DoNothing{
    public:
    void Visit(const A&) override {std::cout << "just a\n";}
};

int main()
{
    StateHolder <A, B, C> holder; // variant state set as default to type A

    PrintVisitor visitor; // works, prints a b c
    //DoNothing visitor; // works, does nothing
    //PrintAVisitor visitor; // does not compile

    holder.Visit(visitor);

    holder.SetState<B>();
    holder.Visit(visitor);

    holder.SetState<C>();
    holder.Visit(visitor);

    return 0;
}
```

Fairly self explanatory I would think - a variadic template class that holds a state as a variant, and an operation to visit that state, which takes an object with overloads for each possible state type.

My problem comes when I want to use a base class for the visitor type, in order to define default behaviour, and then derive from this to create a visitor which only differs for certain types. This is illustrated with the class DoNothing and PrintAVisitor.

This does not compile, even though I would expect it to. I statically specify the concrete type PrintAVisitor, so I would have thought the compiler would be able to match the methods it has inherited from DoNothing. This does not seem to be the case, and I'm not sure why.

Is there another way I can do this, with some using statements, or similar?

Comment: `PrintAVisitor::Visit` shadows that of `DoNothing`. Add `using DoNothing::Visit;` to PrintA's definition.

Comment: Thanks, that fixes it for me. Guess I don't understand quite what shadowing is/does.

Comment: Since there's a method so named, parent's method are not considered for name lookup even if they constitute a better match, unless used explicitly.